# Knockout CSS only applying one class?

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following:

```
<a><i data-bind="css: { 'fa fa-square': !eval(), 'fa fa-check-square-o': eval() }"></i></a>
```

When `eval()` evaluates to `true`, I see the correct classes apply.  However, when `eval()` returns `false`, and `fa fa-square` should be applied, all I see is `fa-square`.  Is there some kind of bug in the css binding, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The css binding adds the css class if the condition evaluates to true, it doesn't override any existing classes. As `fa` appears in both conditions, it doesn't need to be in your binding at all.

Try this:

```
<a><i class="fa" data-bind="css: { 'fa-square': !eval(), 'fa-check-square-o': eval() }"></i></a>
```

EDIT: To answer your original question, multiple css classes within one string seems to still be a bit buggy within Knockout. You can achieve this by separating them out. For example, if you wanted to add `class1 class2` if eval evaluated to true, you could go:

```
<i data-bind="css: { 'class1': eval(), 'class2': eval() }"></i>
```